# Add database name to sql file when exporting using mysqldump via linux

Tags: sql, linux, command-line, mysql

I need to backup a range of databases each day and I would like to do this via command line.

I'm using mysqldump to dump the db into a folder on the root of the server appended with the date. I would like to add the name of the database dynamically to the exported filename, rather than hard coding it into the query. Currently I have:

```
[~]# mysqldump -u user -h localhost -p unique_database_name > unique_database_name_1_$(date +%d%m%y).sql
```

The goal is to have 'unique_database_name' appended to the filename, so the script is a little more portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbs='firstdb seconddb thirddb'

echo -n 'Enter database password: '
read pw

for db in $dbs
do
    mysqldump -u user -h localhost -p$pw $db > $db_1_$(date +%d%m%y).sql
done
```

Comment: Note this does not ensure the backups are consistent with each other.  That is, they are not taken from the same moment in time.

Comment: Agreed - but not part of the OP's stated requirements.